# Laravel as Api server returns CSRF token mismatch when accessing with react app over axios

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, axios

Trying to create Laravel Api app that would be on a different domain with React as frontend app... when attempting to login, after fetching csrf-cookie, and making another request, I get the error:

```
{
    "message": "Network Error",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {
            "FormData": null
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "withCredentials": true,
        "method": "post",
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/login",
        "data": "{\"email\":\"test2@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"test\"}"
    },
    "code": "ERR_NETWORK",
    "status": null
}
```

If I disable

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
```

In my Kernel.php file, everything works fine

This is how I send the request

```js
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const body = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };
    axios.get(csrf).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      axios.post(login, body, {withCredentials:true}).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
  }
```

But if i remove `{withCredentials:true}` I get this error:

message: "Request failed with status code 419"
"CSRF token mismatch."

Cors.php file:

```php
    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: Do you use laravel sanctum? Did you set your frontend app url properly in the .env file? The Default endpoint for sanctum is http://localhost/login without /api, because sanctum is using laravel's default web guard.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sanctum does not allow browser authentications from different domain. It only works on apps on subdomains under one domain. I am assuming your react app is hosted on localhost:3000, your laravel app is hosted on localhost:8000. Those are completely different domains. If you take a closer look, Laravel will not issue a CSRF token and there is no csrf cookie stored in browser. Your option would be to host the apps on same domain. Lets say frontend.app.test for frontend and api.app.test for laravel backend. This can be done with packages like laravel valet.